# Add a spinner loader in between

Tags: jquery, ajax, loading

in between the steps I'd like to add a spinner (just a message Loading for now) is it possible?

Perhaps something like this?

```
$('#loader').show();
   $.ajax({
      success: function(data) {

      //Hide the progress div if loading data is done
      $('#loader').hide();
      }
   });
```

**JS CODE OF MY DEMO:**

```
var prevLink = '<button class="button cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>';
var nextLink = '<button class="button continue" type="button">Confirm purchase</button>';
var navHTML = '<div class="buttons">' + prevLink + nextLink + '</div>';
var FormData = [];

$(function() {
  $('#stepbystep > fieldset').hide().append(navHTML);
  $('#first-step .cancel').remove();
  $('#last-step .continue').remove();

  $('#first-step').fadeIn();
  setHeight();

  $('button.continue').click(function() {
      var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');            
      if (whichStep == 'first-step') {               
      } else if (whichStep == 'second-step')    {
      } else if (whichStep == 'third-step')     {
      } else if (whichStep == 'fourth-step')    { 
      } else if (whichStep == 'last-step')      {
      }
      $(this).parent().parent().hide(300).next().show(300);
      setHeight();
  });
  $('button.cancel').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(300).prev().fadeIn(300);
  });
})
```

FIXED DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/59fNR/2/

Comment: What do you mean with _without hacking it_? Hacking what?

Comment: I don't want to add complicated code on it! just a spinner in between the steps.

Comment: how are you going to the next step?

Comment: @putvande  did you check my Demo? is pretty clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a function to run on the start and stop of every jQuery ajax call, like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loading").show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Then you don't have to do anything on each actual ajax request, it'll automatically run. Just change #loading to whatever the id of your loader element is.

Comment: thanks,  but not sure I'm able to make it working. could u please have a look at this? http://jsfiddle.net/59fNR/1/

Comment: Your code isn't actually using any ajax calls, so the code I provided isn't ever going to run. I'm not really clear on when you want the loading code to be run, but if you aren't trying to show it during the time in which an ajax call is running, then that's not actually going to be what you need. What's being "loaded" in your code? Maybe you can put some comments to explain it?